# Does incomplete LU preconditioning improve the asymptotic scaling of Krylov subspace methods?

Tags: preconditioning, matrix-factorization, krylov-method

It is well known that unpreconditioned Krylov subspace methods applied to the finite-difference-discretised Poisson equation with $n$ grid points per direction require $O(n \, |\log(\varepsilon)|)$ iterations to reduce the error in the initial guess by a factor $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. This is typically a prohibitively large number of iterations; hence it is often suggested to reduce the number of iterations through incomplete LU (ILU) preconditioning.

My question is: does ILU reduce the $\text{# iterations} = O(n \,|\log(\varepsilon)|)$  estimate asymptotically (e.g. to $\text{# iterations} = O(\sqrt{n} \,|\log(\varepsilon)|)$), or does it merely reduce the prefactor implied by the big-O notation?

My own experiments seem to suggest that ILU preconditioning only improves the prefactor, but maybe I am not using the method properly?

Comment: According to the below reference, "the speed of convergence of conjugate gradients is proportional to the square root of the condition number". Perhaps your system's condition number is growing faster than your preconditioner is reducing it. 

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702005344

Comment: ILU is not even guaranteed to improve the condition number. It just sometimes works, or in your words, reduces the prefactor. If you are only interested in the Poisson equation, something like ADI will both be equally simple and more efficient.

Comment: ADI sounds like a good idea! I wonder why standard textbooks like Saad (2003) or Demmel (1997) do not mention it. Maybe that is because ADI cannot be generalised to general triangular / tetrahedral meshes?

Comment: If you're interested in Poisson, use multi-grid.

Comment: There are also many many variations on ILU: Do you want to strengthen the diagonal? Add some fill-in? Do you want a pre-determined fill-in pattern, or a drop threshold? My experience is that ILU working on the same sparsity pattern as the matrix itself is nearly useless, but carefully tuned variations can be quite effective. But it requires a lot of work and insight to use ILU right. For the Poisson equation, that's not necessary: We know that either algebraic or geometric multigrid cannot be beat.

Comment: Actually, my main concern is how to teach preconditioning to my students. For this purpose, I use the Poisson equation as a model problem to illustrate sparse factorisation, Krylov subspace methods and multigrid, but of course the techniques that I teach should also allow them to solve other equations.

Comment: ADI does not generalize well, it is also somehow outdated. There are some uses for it with advection-diffusion equations. However, in that case, ADI preconditioners become pretty expensive. I suggested ADI over multi-grid, because IMO, multi-grid is rather involved for most general topic classes. However, if you want to teach preconditioning, it is definitely the way to go. I would suggest you to take a look at Chapter 2 of "Finite Elements and Fast Iterative Solvers" by Elman, Silvester and Wathen. They both cover convergence results for CG and optimality of multi-grid.